# Why I cannot get tasks in Flink?

Tags: apache-flink

I am trying to run flink for the first time. After starting, I get this error in the task executer log:

2019-02-02 23:40:17,031 INFO  org.apache.flink.runtime.taskexecutor.TaskExecutor            - Could not resolve ResourceManager address akka.tcp://flink@149.28.34.105:6123/user/resourcemanager, retrying in 10000 ms: Ask timed out on [ActorSelection[Anchor(akka.tcp://flink@149.28.34.105:6123/), Path(/user/resourcemanager)]] after [10000 ms]. Sender[null] sent message of type "akka.actor.Identify"..

I get this over and over.  I able to launch the console but it doesn't have any task allocation.  I don't see any issue in the standalone log.

Any idea what could be wrong?

---

I am not running a job.  I am just trying to start up flink using the start_cluster.sh in bin folder and this is what I am getting upon startup.

Comment: Can you please share 

a) your code (minimal example)
b) some more details on how you try to run your job

At the first glance it looks like you try to submit your job to a cluster which doesn't have any or enough task managers.

Comment: I edited my question to include the details. I am just attempting to start the cluster and I get this error.

Comment: Were you able to figure this out? I'm running into the same issue.